# Summary and Histogram of large raster Layer

Tags: r, histogram, na, summary

I'm a very beginner in R and have a few questions regarding a large raster layer (Barrow_DEM.tif, 2,5GB) containing an elevation model. Additionaly there's a shape file (Barrow_DTLB.shp) with 10 polygons, for which I want to have the elevation data from the raster. Both files have the same spatial extend and the correct coordinates, projection, etc.

```
`setwd("...")
Barrow_DEM <- raster("Barrow_DEM.tif")
Barrow_DTLB <- st_read("Barrow_DTLB.shp")
Barrow_DTLB_Buffer <- st_read("Barrow_DTLB_BufferOUT.shp")
Barrow_lake <- crop(Barrow_DEM, extent(Barrow_DTLB))
raster_lake <- rasterize(Barrow_DTLB, Barrow_lake, mask = TRUE)
summary(raster_lake)`
```

The result is shown as follows:

```
summary(raster_lake)
        layer
Min.        0
1st Qu.     2
Median      3
3rd Qu.     8
Max.       12
NA's        0
Warning message:
In .local(object, ...) :
  summary is an estimate based on a sample of 1e+05 cells (0.02% of all cells)
```

The result for the Histogram is the following:

```
hist(raster_lake, col=rgb(0,0,1,0.5),  breaks=100, ylab= "Frequency", xlab= "Height", main= "Histogram DTLB Barrow")
Warning message: In .hist1(x, maxpixels = maxpixels, main = main, plot = plot, ...) :
  0% of the raster cells were used (of which 92% were NA). 7651 values used
```

I already tried this from another discussion here, but it didn't help me.
   `replaceNA <- function(x, na.rm, ...){ 
  if(is.na(x[1]))
    return(0)
  else
    return(x)
} 
raster_lake <- calc(raster_lake, fun = replaceNA)`

It seems like all data values in the new raster_lake file, which are outside the polygons got NA value. How do I get rid of these NAs? 
I would like to get the full histogram as well as some statsitical data such as median, mean, min, max for all polygons and for each polygon seperately.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well you would like to compute a histogram of the raster values while removing the NA's.

You can extract the raster values, remove the NA's and make an histogram of the values:

```
require(raster)
require(sp)
require(gstat)

# load some data and make a raster object
data(meuse.grid)
meuse.grid <- data.frame(x =meuse.grid$y , y =meuse.grid$x , val = meuse.grid$dist)
coordinates(meuse.grid) <- ~x+y
gridded(meuse.grid) <- T
meuse.grid <- raster(meuse.grid)

# get the values from the raster, remove the NA's and make an histogram
hist(na.omit(getValues(meuse.grid)))
```

## EDIT

In case you have a large dataset and it takes too much RAM (common in R), you can create a ff object vector which stores the data on the disk:

```
require(ff)

# create a ff object from the vector or the raster values (NA's are included)
val.Ras <- ff(getValues(meuse.grid))

# you can use this ff object as any other R vector files
hist(val.Ras[,3])

# check that it takes less memory
object.size(val.Ras)
64944 bytes

object.size(getValues(meuse.grid))
3168 bytes
```

The object size is reduced by 95%!

Comment: Thanks! hist(na.omit(getValues(meuse.grid))) helped me for middle sized raster file, but for the skript above, it still did not work. There is the error message: cannot allocate vector of size 3.8GB
If you have any additional idea of how to get rid of the NA data, that would be great

Comment: I propose to convert the object to a ff object. It takes less memory space. Made an udpate.

Answer (score 0):

The ff option will not work because the getValues() or values() is executed first. You will still run out of memory. The only option that I think you have is to partition your large raster to tiles, compute the histogram for each tile using predefined breaks, and then merge the tile histogram. Or get a computer with much more RAM!

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
library(raster)

v  <- getValues(raster_lake) # extract values from raster layer into a vector
v2 <- v[!is.na(v)]           # remove NA values from the vector

length(v); length(v2)        # prove that the second object is smaller
hist(v2)
```